# Using Flink Table API inside flatMap getting serialization exception

Tags: apache-flink

I was trying to use table api inside flatMap by passing the flink env object to the flatMap object. But I was getting serialization exception which tells that I have added some field which cannot be serializable.

Could you please give some light on this?

Regards,
Sajeev

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass the `ExecutionEnvironment` into a `Function`. It would be like passing Flink into Flink.

The Table API is an abstraction on top of the `DataSet`/`DataStream` APIs. If you want to use both the Table API and the lower API, you can use `TableEnvironment#toDataSet/fromDataSet` to change between the APIs even between DataSet operators.

```
DataSet<Integer> ds = env.fromElements(1, 2, 3);
BatchTableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);
Table t = tEnv.fromDataSet(ds, "intCol"); // continue in Table API
Table t2 = t.select("intCol.cast(STRING)"); // do something with table
DataSet<String> ds2 = tEnv.toDataSet(t2); // continue in DataSet API
```

Comment: "It would be like passing Flink into Flink." :)

Comment: Got it. So is there any way to use Table API inside the flatMap?.